# Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in the neoclassical growth model

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, dynamical-systems, economics

I have a doubt regarding the use of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in a dynamic optimization problem. Exactly, the problem is the neoclassical growth model (or Ramsey model). In the website that I post below, in page 14, they invoke the aforementioned theorem so as to prove the existence of a solution. This is not the unic work that mention the theorem for the same purpouse. My question is, how can I use the B-W theorem so as to proof the existence of a solution in a such a casa?

The link to the website: [https://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~nankuang/Macro%20Theory%20III/Lecture%20Notes/The%20Neoclassical%20Growth%20Model%20in%20Discrete%20Time.pdf](https://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/%7Enankuang/Macro%20Theory%20III/Lecture%20Notes/The%20Neoclassical%20Growth%20Model%20in%20Discrete%20Time.pdf)

Comment: Where does your doubt come from? Which condition(s) of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem do you think might not hold here?

Comment: Hello. My doubt is related to the use of this theorem to guarantee the existence of a solution in this problem.

Comment: Which condition(s) of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem do you think might not hold here?

Comment: I am not asking about which condition is not fulfilling here. I think that conditions hold. However, i cannot see the ituition about why when conditions of BW theorem are fulfilled a solution to that optimization dynamic problem exists. Thank you !